# toggle checkboxes with javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of checkboxes that are organized into categories. I have a checkbox for each category that toggles the corresponding group of checkboxes. For some reason, it isn't working in IE; however, I was able to get separate select all/clear all links to work fine.

See code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mobilemelody/DyZF4/1/

For more context, these boxes are being used to turn on and off google fusion layers in the maps API. thanks!

**EDIT**

Sorry, I originally put the code in JSfiddle because I thought that would be easier for people..

Javascript:

```
function toggleOn(source) {
        var checkboxes = source;
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
    }
    function toggleOff(source) {
        var checkboxes = source;
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
    function toggle(toggleBox, source) {
        var checkboxes = source;
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
            checkboxes[i].checked = toggleBox.checked;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><label><strong>Routes:</strong></label></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="toggle-local" onClick="toggle(this, document.getElementsByClassName('local'))">local</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="17" value="17" class="local"/><label>17</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="19" value="19" class="local"/><label>19</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="22" value="22" class="local"/><label>22</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="23" value="23" class="local"/><label>23</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="29" value="29" class="local"/><label>29</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="35" value="35" class="local"/><label>35</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="36" value="36" class="local"/><label>36</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="45" value="45" class="local"/><label>45</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="49" value="49" class="local"/><label>49</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="51" value="51" class="local"/><label>51</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="71" value="71" class="local"/><label>71</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="toggle-stage" onClick="toggle(this, document.getElementsByClassName('stage'))">stage</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="61" value="61" class="stage"/><label>61</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="68" value="68" class="stage"/><label>68</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="toggle-shuttle" onClick="toggle(this, document.getElementsByClassName('shuttle'))">shuttle</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="222" value="222" class="shuttle"/><label>222</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="233" value="233" class="shuttle"/><label>233</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="257" value="257" class="shuttle"/><label>257</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="259" value="259" class="shuttle"/><label>259</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="toggle-school" onClick="toggle(this, document.getElementsByClassName('school'))">school</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="113" value="113" class="school"/><label>113</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="117" value="117" class="school"/><label>117</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="125" value="125" class="school"/><label>125</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="126" value="126" class="school"/><label>126</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="127" value="127" class="school"/><label>127</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="route" id="139" value="139" class="school"/><label>139</label></td>
    </tr></table>
</div>

<a id="select-all" onClick="toggleOn(document.getElementsByName('route'))" style="cursor: pointer;">select all</a> | 
<a id="clear-all" onClick="toggleOff(document.getElementsByName('route'))" style="cursor: pointer;">clear all</a>
```

Comment: There seems to be no question here.  Let us know when you figure it out.

Comment: You need to post the code you're having the problem with, not some code which is actually working fine for you.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/lefnire/T6b8H/12/ with jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` is **not** supported by **IE < 9**. However, you can use [this](http://polyfilljs.com/js/mylibs/getelementsbyclassname.js) [pollyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill), which will define it for *legacy* browsers that don't:

```
(function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName = function(classes) {
            return this.querySelectorAll('.' + classes.replace(' ', ' .'));
        }
}());
```

<sub>Another alternative is to use jQuery's [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selectors instead.</sub>